# Regex modify connection string

Tags: c#, regex

Lets say I have this SQL Server connection string in C#:

```
Driver={SQL Server};server=.\sqlexpress;uid=myid;pwd=password;
```

I would like to remove the Driver= portion of the string, no matter where it appears in the string.  So that afterwards it looks like this:

```
server=.\sqlexpress;uid=myid;pwd=password;
```

I have been trying Regex for a while with no luck.

Comment: Could you put that regex you tried in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
string pattern = @"\bDriver=[^;]+;";
string replacement = "";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir: indeed, line breaks are included. Is it a problem?

Comment: Doh! I was making it too complex. Thanks!

Comment: This breaks if `Driver` is at the end of the string without the `;` separator. `server=.\sqlexpress;uid=myid;pwd=password;Driver={SQL Server}`

Comment: @wdosanjos: in this specific case you can use `(?:;|$)` instead of `;`

Comment: To be more waterproof, you can replace `\b` with `(?<=^|[;\n])[^\S\n]*`

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `OdbcConnectionStringBuilder` class, which will parse this for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
res = Regex.Replace(connStr, "Driver=[{][^}]*[}];", "");
```

For your string it produces

```
server=.\sqlexpress;uid=myid;pwd=password;
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/PF7k7F)

Answer (score 0):

Might not work as it stands but I hope you get the idea:

```
string result = string.Join(";", connectionString
    .Split(';')
    .Where(p => !p.StartsWith('Driver'))
```

As a side note, I find it amazing that there are four completely different solutions ;)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer SLaks gave:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var connStr = "Driver={SQL Server};server=.\\sqlexpress;uid=myid;pwd=password;";
    var builder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.ConnectionString = connStr;
    builder.Remove("Driver");
    connStr = builder.ConnectionString;
    Assert.AreEqual("server=.\\sqlexpress;uid=myid;pwd=password", connStr);
}
```